# Fade elements in when parent style = X

Tags: jquery

I have a slider on my homepage with my markup as so...

```
       <li id="fragment-3" class="slides virtualsation ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="display: list-item;">
              <h1>Virtualisation</h1> 
              <p>By implementing virtualisation into  Council  managed to save them over £250,000 in annual expenditure.</p>
              <div class="animation">
                    <div class="big-server"><img src="_includes/images/sliders/big-server.png"></div>
                    <div class="arrow"><img src="_includes/images/sliders/arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="small-server-one"><img title="Title Text Blah" src="_includes/images/sliders/small-server.png"></div>
                    <div class="small-server-two"><img title="Title Text Blah" src="_includes/images/sliders/small-server.png"></div>
                    <div class="small-desktop"><img title="Title Text Blah" src="_includes/images/sliders/small-desktop.png"></div>
              </div>
        </li>
```

I want each child in my animation element to fade in  when the parent li has the inline style of display:list-item;

Is this possible with jQuery?

I though about using .closest() but wwasnt sure how Id target a div with an inline style...

Comment: is this being driven by jQueryUI tabs widget? If so easy to bind to tabs events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make it a lot easier if you showed us when and how you change the display to list-item.

You could look op the jquery function $.Deffered, and attach it to the method that changes the display of the li element. That way you can later on make a function that listens to rather the display has been set to list-item or not.

Or you could animate it within the method that defines the li display, like so:

*Since it is a slider, I assume it changes when a arrow is pressed, and that the list item you've showen us, is one slider amongst others.*

```
// when you click next
$('.arrow-next').on('click', function(){

    // hides the current, sets the next to list-item and caches the 'next' li
    var nextLi  = $('li.current').css('display','hidden').next('li').css('display','list-item')

    // fades in every element in the div.animation that is within the 'next' li element
    $('div.animation *', nextLi).fadeIn()


})
```

Hope this could help you. If the example above did not solve your problem, then i'm not quite sure how you handle the transition from not being list-item, into being list-item. Anyways, hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, something like this would work:

```
var hasInlineListItem = $('#whatever').closest('li').is(function () {
    return this.style.display == 'list-item';
});

if (hasInlineListItem) {
    //do whatever you want
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo to illustrate how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/yJKrH/)

jQuery has several [filter methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/) that you can use. I used [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) here, which will return a boolean.